# Dotnet Publish (framework Dependent) Creates Dependent DLLs

Tags: deployment, .net-core

I am developing an ASP.NetCore web application using Visual Studio 2017. Previously when I ran `dotnet publish --configuration Release --output "path to output directory"` I simply got the Project DLL and the Views DLL. All of a sudden I now get all of my dependency DLLs, such as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` and `AutoMapper.dll`. Now my deployment folder is much larger as a result.

`dotnet --version` returns 2.1.500. I tried setting `--self-contained false` but it made no difference. Can anyone explain this behaviour please?

Comment: any idea what you did differently before and after the all of a sudden? If you really want to remove everything, you will have to remove the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package and add each required package one by one

Comment: I suspect a recent Microsoft Update on my Windows 10 may have updated the dotnet SDK. I tried pointing my project to a previous specific version by creating a global.json file and specifying `"version: 2.1.403"` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Actually, this is what is be design (having all dlls). What I was trying to understand is how you had only two dlls at the start.